# How many times does a hash function have to be evaluated?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I have the following homework assignment:

> $n$ is an even number, $1^n$ and $0^n$ are $n$-bit strings and $x$, $y$ and $z$ are arbitrary strings of length $n$.
>
> How many evaluations of hash function $h= does solving the following evaluation require?
>
> $$h(1^n || h(x) || h(y) || h(x \oplus y \oplus h(y \oplus h(y)))) = h(0^n || h(z)||0^n||0^n)$$

I know it requires $n^{(n/2)}$ executions to find a collision. Within the outer hash functions, there are 4 distinct hash evaluations.

Am I correct in assuming the answer is $4 \times n^{(n/2)}$?

Comment: What does "solving the following evaluation" mean?  Is it the same as "Find x, y, z such that ...".  What is the length of the output of *h* ?  Is it *n*, or could it be (for example) 1?